# How to edit html after rendering in Druapl 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I need to change the rendered html code before displaying it. I tried to use hooks, but they don't work for me. if I try to use hook_views_pre_render like (var_dump($view); die;) it's don't affect to my output What I need to do? Real task is to replace all external links. Thanks :-)

Comment: What kind of content you want to change? Nodes (entities) or view's output? Is maybe hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view what you are looking for: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x

Comment: thank you for the answer. I put my code  hook_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  dump($entity); die;} in my myinfo.module and no sense at all to pages. What's wrong?

Comment: The "hook_" must be changed with your module name. Like this: myinfo_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) { dump($entity); die;}